# Determine whether $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n-1}{3n-1}$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n-1}{3n-1}$$

$$\begin{align}
s_m &= \sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{n-1}{3n-1} \\
\lim(s_m) &= \lim \frac{n-1}{3n-1} \\
\end{align}$$

Since the limit of the sum goes towards infinity, we use l'hospital rule and I end up getting $\frac{1}{3}$.

From here, I am not sure if I am understanding the convergence/divergence tests correctly. My textbook says

> If the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is convergent, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ is convergent and the $\lim_{n\to\infty}=0$

What I have found is that the limit of the sum ${s_n}$ converges to $\frac{1}{3}$. Therefore I can assume that the series is convergent and the limit of the infinite series is 0?

Comment: The individual terms in the sum converge to $1/3$. So eventually you're adding up infinitely many $1/3$'s, which is infinity.

Comment: Don't confuse $a_n$ with $s_n=a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_n$.

Comment: What your textbook says is that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0.$  That is, the *terms* go to zero, not the sum.  You have shown that the term go to $\frac13\neq0$, which proves that the sum is *not* convergent.

Comment: If the limit of the summand is not zero, that is $  \lim_\limits{n \to \infty}a_n \ne 0,$ then the series must diverge

Comment: Evan, you can often guess whether a series converges or not by just adding up some of the terms (computing the partial sums) before applying convergence tests.  It's not proof, but it might help your intuition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n-1}{3n-1}= \dfrac{1}{3}\neq0 \implies\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n-1}{3n-1}=\infty$ or diverges.